# JavaFX: Anchor Pane constraints inside a tab

Tags: java, javafx, tabs

I have a JavaFX application with multiple fxml files, with a MainPanel set up like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import java.net.URL?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainPanelController">
   <children>
      <TabPane fx:id="mainTabPane" prefHeight="570.0" prefWidth="880.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" tabMaxHeight="20.0" tabMaxWidth="3520.0" tabMinHeight="20.0" tabMinWidth="50.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <tabs>
                <Tab fx:id="tab1" text="Tab 1" />
                <Tab fx:id="tab2" text="Tab 2" />
                <Tab fx:id="tab3" text="Tab 3" />
                <Tab fx:id="tab4" text="Tab 4" />
                <Tab fx:id="tab5" text="Tab 5" />
                <Tab fx:id="tab6" text="Tab 6" />
                <Tab fx:id="tab7" text="Tab 7" />
            </tabs>
        </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The process goes like this:

1. The application is launched by:

   ```
   Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
   primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 880, 570));
   primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
   primaryStage.show();
   ```

With the Login fxml being:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="mainAnchorPane" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="880.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="LoginController">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="340.0" layoutY="186.0" spacing="5.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="186.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="340.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="340.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="186.0">
         <children>
              <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="GM-SIS">
                  <font>
                      <Font name="Helvetica" size="60.0" />
                  </font>
              </Label>
              <TextField fx:id="userField" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
              <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
              <Button fx:id="loginButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#login" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Login">
                  <font>
                      <Font name="Helvetica" size="13.0" />
                  </font>
              </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="270.0" layoutY="265.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="User">
         <font>
            <Font name="Helvetica" size="13.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="270.0" layoutY="300.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Password" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

2. The user clicks the login button, the MainPanel is loaded like this:

   ```
   Node mainNode = FXMLLoader.load(Login.class.getResource(fxmlPath));
   mainAnchorPane.getChildren().setAll(mainNode);
   ```
3. The MainPanel Controller then loads each individual fxml into each tab in a similar way. I've tried something like this:

   ```
   tab1.setContent(loadedNode);
   ```

And this:

```
tab1AnchorPane.getChildren().setAll(tab1Node);
```

I've tried having the Tab with no children and just loading into it. I've tried having an AnchorPane inside the tab. I've tried a combination of HBoxes/VBoxes with AnchorPanes, with no success.

The AnchorPane constraints work if I load the fxml file individually. However, when I try to load it into a tab, it doesn't work.

Here's an fxml which works if loaded separately, and doesn't when loaded into a tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="tab1AnchorPane" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="880.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Tab1Controller">
    <children>
        <VBox prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="880.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <TableView fx:id="table" editable="true" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="474.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="column1" prefWidth="75.0" text="Column 1" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="column2" prefWidth="75.0" text="Column 2" />
                    </columns>
                    <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                    </VBox.margin>
                </TableView>
                <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="880.0" spacing="50.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <children>
                        <VBox spacing="50.0">
                            <children>
                                <Button fx:id="button1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#action1" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Button 1" />
                                <Button fx:id="button2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#action2" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Button 2" />
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox spacing="10.0">
                            <children>
                                <Button fx:id="button3" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#action3" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Button 3" />
                                <Button fx:id="button4" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#action4" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Button 4" />
                                <Button fx:id="button5" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#action5" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Button 5" />
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox spacing="10.0">
                            <children>
                                <Button fx:id="button6" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#action6" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Button 6" />
                                <Button fx:id="button7" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#action7" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Button 7" />
                                <Button fx:id="button8" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#action8" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Button 8" />
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox spacing="50.0">
                            <children>
                                <Button fx:id="button9" maxWidth="150.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#" prefHeight="30.0" text="Button 9" />
                                <Button fx:id="button10" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#action9" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Button 10" />
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </children>
                    <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                    </VBox.margin>
                </HBox>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Not even the TabPane inside the MainPanel resizes properly. What am I doing wrong here? I'm feeling a bit lost.

Comment: To much work to recreate you problem with what's given. Do you have the project on GitHub?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Unfortunately I can't really share the entire project. Was hoping this was some simple error on my part. One of those solved by a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

I got also similar situation you mentioned.

When some node is added on root pane loaded by fxml, root pane dosen't resized corresponding with stage at all. (I suspect it may bug on JavaFx.)

So I add listener on stage's widthProperty (or heightProperty) to resize stage's root pane simultaneously.

```
    Scene      scene = stage.getScene();
    AnchorPane root  = (AnchorPane) scene.getRoot();
    scene.widthProperty().addListener( ( observable, oldValue, newValue ) -> root.setPrefWidth( newValue.doubleValue() ) );
    scene.heightProperty().addListener( ( observable, oldValue, newValue ) -> root.setPrefHeight( newValue.doubleValue() ) );
```